# How to map key/value partitions in paralell in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, spark-streaming

I have a Spark Streaming program running in local mode in which I receive JSON messages from a TCP socket connection, several per batch interval.

Each of these messages has an ID, which I use to create a key/value JavaPairDStream, such that in each partition of the RDD inside my JavaDStream, there is a key/value pair, with a single message per partition.

My goal now, is to group the messages that have the same ID together in the same partition, so that I can map them in parallel, each partition being processed by a different core.

Following is my code:

```
JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> streamData2 = ssc.socketTextStream(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]),
            StorageLevels.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER);
JavaDStream<String>streamData1=streamData2.repartition(1);

JavaPairDStream<String,String> streamGiveKey= streamData1.mapPartitionsToPair(new PairFlatMapFunction<Iterator<String>, String, String>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<Tuple2<String, String>> call(Iterator<String> stringIterator) throws Exception {

            ArrayList<Tuple2<String,String>>a= new ArrayList<Tuple2<String, String>>();

            while (stringIterator.hasNext()){
                String c=stringIterator.next();
                if(c==null){
                    return null;

                }

                JsonMessage retMap = new Gson().fromJson(c,JsonMessage.class);
                String key= retMap.getSid();
                Tuple2<String,String> b= new Tuple2<String,String>(key,c);
                a.add(b);

            }

            return a;
        }
    });
```

So, at the end of this code, I have a DStream with an RDD that has only one partition because of `repartition{1}`, with all the key/value pairs inside it.

How should I proceed now to group the messages that have the same key, and put them into different partitions so I can map them separately?

Comment: Does my previous answer to the other question cover this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37908890/how-to-group-key-values-by-partition-in-spark ?  If not, please let us know what more you need here.

Comment: Yes, it does, thank you so much. I actually have another question regarding this, but I will create a new one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was - according to the OP - addressed by a simultaneous answer to another question here: [How to group key/values by partition in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37907715/how-to-map-key-value-partitions-in-paralell-in-spark-streaming?noredirect=1#comment63271526_37907715/%22How%20to%20group%20key/values%20by%20partition%20in%20Spark?%22)