# How to group key/values by partition in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, spark-streaming

I have a Spark Streaming application which receives several JSON messages per second, each of these having an ID which identifies their source.

Using this ID as a key, I am able to perform a `MapPartitionsToPair`, thus creating a JavaPairDStream, with an RDD of key/value pairs, one key value pair per partition (so if I received 5 JSON messages for example, I get an RDD with 5 partitions, each with the ID of the message as a key, and the JSON message itself as the value).

What I want to do now, is I want to group all values that have the same key into the same partition. So for example, if I have 3 partitions with key 'a' and 2 partitions with key 'b', I want to create a new RDD with 2 partitions instead of 5, each partition containing all the values that one key has, one for'a' and one for 'b'.

How can I accomplish this?
This is my code so far:

```
JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> streamData2 = ssc.socketTextStream(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]),
            StorageLevels.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER);

JavaPairDStream<String,String> streamGiveKey= streamData2.mapPartitionsToPair(new PairFlatMapFunction<Iterator<String>, String, String>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<Tuple2<String, String>> call(Iterator<String> stringIterator) throws Exception {

            ArrayList<Tuple2<String,String>>a= new ArrayList<Tuple2<String, String>>();

            while (stringIterator.hasNext()){
                String c=stringIterator.next();
                if(c==null){
                    return null;

                }

                JsonMessage retMap = new Gson().fromJson(c,JsonMessage.class);
                String key= retMap.getSid();
                Tuple2<String,String> b= new Tuple2<String,String>(key,c);
                a.add(b);

                System.out.print(b._1+"_"+b._2);
                // }
                //break;
            }


            return a;
        }
    });
```

//I create a JavaPairDStream in which each partition contains one key/value pair.

I tried to use `grouByKey()`, but no matter what the number of messages were, I always got a partition number of 2.

How should I do this?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Why would you like 1 element per partition? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the

```
groupByKey(Integer numPartitions)
```

and set the `numPartitions` equal to the number of distinct keys you have.

But ..  you will need to know ***how many distinct keys do you have*** up front. Do you have that information? Probably not. So then .. you would need to do some extra (/redundant) work. E.g. use

```
countByKey
```

as the first step.  That is faster than groupByKey - so at least you were not *doubling* the total processing time.

**Update** The OP asked about why they are getting 2 partitions by default.

The default `groupByKey` uses a `defaultPartitioner()` method

```
groupByKey(defaultPartitioner(self))
```

- which selects the `Partitioner` from  the parent partition with the largest cardinality.

-- or it will use `spark.default.parallelism`

Comment: Thank you, this definitely solves my issue. However, just one question: do you know why `groupByKey()` returns 2 partitions by default? No matter how many inputs I send per batch interval, or outputs that I have, it seems that groupByKey is independent of all that. It just returns 2 when I do `getNumPartitions`